# Confusing grammar of "As usual"

Tags: meaning-in-context, as

If I were to write "He is just doing not good as usual",

which one does this mean? "He is doing badly as usual." or "He is good usually, but did badly this time."

Comment: *Not good as usual* means bad as usual (a comma after "good" would help); *not as good as usual* means worse than usual.

Comment: Another possibility, for clarity, is - "I'm not doing good, as usual" (I'm doing badly, as always"

Comment: The usual adverb is _well_; 'doing good' is (unless informal/slang) the equivalent of 'acting benevolently'.

Comment: The phrase "doing not good" sounds incorrect to me, so I would suggest using one of your alternatives instead.  If you mean "doing badly", then say that.  If you mean the latter, you can say "He is just not doing *as good* as usual."

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to note that there is potential for ambiguity with **as usual** especially when a negative is involved. The placement of the phrase is important.

> As usual, the horse is not eating.<sup>unambiguous</sup>
>
> The horse is not eating as usual. <sup>ambiguous</sup>

In the second sentence, the horse might normally have a good appetite but today something is unusual; or the horse might always turns its nose away from the food it is given. We don't know without further context.

In the *spoken* word,  this ambiguity is avoided by natural syntactic pauses and intonation patterns.  If the horse never eats, **as usual** would be separated from the matrix clause (The horse is not eating) with a distinct intervening pause:

The horse is not eating ... as usual.

and we can indicate such a pause in writing with a comma.

> The horse is not eating, as usual. <sup>the horse never eats</sup>

<sup>NOTE: When I say **distinct**, I mean that it can be identified as what it is, even though it might be very brief. Native speakers use and understand these pauses and micro-pauses and intonations without having to think about them.</sup>

If the horse usually eats, there would be no such intervening pause, and "eating as usual" would be a coherent phrase:

The horse is not {eating as usual}.

> The horse is not eating as usual. <sup>the horse usually eats</sup>

But it is best not to rely upon punctuation to disambiguate. Instead you should place the phrase where it cannot be misconstrued:

> As usual, the horse is not eating. <sup>the horse never eats</sup>